# PostgreSQL fails to start on Windows XP

Tags: postgresql, service, windows-xp

I am attempting to set up a Windows XP Test Agent running Ruby on Rails against a PostgreSQL Database. I've installed PostgreSQL 9.2 for Windows, with default settings. However, when I attempt to start the service from the Service Control Panel, the following error message appears(irrelevantly of which User I attempt to set it to):

```
   The postgres-9.2 -PostgreSQL Server 9.2 service on Local Computer started and then stopped. Some services 
   stop automatically if they have work to do, for example, the Performance Logs and Alerts service.
```

If I attempt to launch it from the command line (whether cmd.exe or git bash doesn't matter with):

```
   E:\PostgreSQL\9.2\bin\pg_ctl.exe start  -D E:\PostgreSQL\9.2\data
```

It will claim:

```
   server starting
```

However it will fail to start (rake db:migrate will report the server as not running, the postgresql process is missing from Task Manager, the Service is listed as down in the Service List, and

```
  E:\PostgreSQL\9.2\bin\pg_ctl.exe stop  -D E:\PostgreSQL\9.2\data
```

Will report

```
  pg_ctl: PID file "E:/PostgreSQL/9.2/data/postmaster.pid" does not exist Is server running?
```

While attempting to start it as a server through pg_ctl:

```
  E:\PostgreSQL\9.2\bin\pg_ctl.exe runservice  -D E:\PostgreSQL\9.2\data
```

Fails with:

```
  pg_ctl: could not start service PostgreSQL: error code 1063
```

EDIT:

the contents of pg_hba:

```
 # TYPE  DATABASE        USER            ADDRESS                 METHOD
 local   all             all                all                  trust
 # IPv4 local connections:
 host    all             all                all                  trust
 host    all             all             127.0.0.1/32            trust
 # IPv6 local connections:
 #host    all             all             ::1/128                trust
 # Allow replication connections from localhost, by a user with the
 # replication privilege.
 #host    replication     all                all                 trust
 #host    replication     postgres        127.0.0.1/32           trust
 #host    replication     postgres        ::1/128                trust
```

Checking in pg_log as per comments below:

```
 2012-10-28 22:47:44 PDT LOG:  local connections are not supported by this build
 2012-10-28 22:47:44 PDT CONTEXT:  line 78 of configuration file "E:/PostgreSQL/9.2/data/pg_hba.conf"
 2012-10-28 22:47:44 PDT FATAL:  could not load pg_hba.conf
```

Line 78 is

```
 local   all             all                all                  trust
```

The same error still occurs when running as a service (whether through pg_ctl runservice or from the services control panel). However pg_ctl start now starts postgres without incident.

I'll go with "good enough"

PS: The Event Log entries merely say "Timed out waiting for server startup"

Comment: Look in `E:\PostgreSQL\9.2\data\pg_log`. What do the server logs say? Also examine Event Viewer (in Administrative Tools in Control Panel) after trying to start the server as a service. Anything in the event logs?

Comment: Just because I spent 5 hours trying to figure out similar problem: If `pg_hba.conf` has IPv6 rule and system (e.g. WinXP) doesn't support it the service won't start, however it is still possible to start postgres as an application via `pg_ctl`. Removing IPv6 rule solves the problem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*UPDATE* After edits to question:

Delete the lines from `pg_hba.conf` that begin with `local`. They relate to UNIX socket connections, which PostgreSQL does not support. Then, unless something else is also wrong, you should be able to start PostgreSQL. Most likely you copied and pasted a `pg_hba.conf` from a site that talks about PostgreSQL on Mac OS X or Linux, where `local` connections are supported.

If Pg still fails to start after fixing `pg_hba.conf`, check the logs again and see what else it's complaining about.

By the way, in general I don't recommend trying to run PostgreSQL both as a service and via `pg_ctl` from the same data directory. You're likely to land up with file systems permissions problems that are difficult and annoying to resolve, especially on Windows.

---

In addition to @mvp's suggestions, it's possible that you are trying to start PostgreSQL under a user that is a member of the Administrators group. This is not permitted and will fail. I disagree with that policy, but that's how it is at the moment.

By default 9.2 is set up to run under the NetworkService, so that should not be a problem. If you configured it to run under a different user account this could be your problem, and it could be the problem when running it manually too.

It's more likely that when starting it manually you just don't have file system permissions to the data directory.

BTW, if `E:\` is FAT32, there's your problem. FAT32 is not supported. You must use NTFS.

Rather than stab in the dark, you should really be looking at the server logs in `E:\PostgreSQL\9.2\data\pg_log` and the event viewer to see what's causing it to fail to start.

Comment: E: is NTFS and it WAS temporarily set up to run off my user because I had been mucking about, thanks for reminding me to change it back, however the error (when starting as a service) persists.

Comment: @AbrahamP Looks like your `pg_hba.conf` is busted; see updated answer

Comment: Workaround is to use Scheduled Tasks. However if anyone has any ideas as to how to fix the service runners, I am most definitely still interested.

Comment: @AbrahamP Hard to say without updated logs after fixing `pg_hba.conf`, but I'd say your data directory permissions are probably hosed from attempts to start the server as your own user account, as @ mvp suggested.

Comment: The Event Log entries merely say "Timed out waiting for server startup"(still)

Comment: @AbrahamP The PostgreSQL server logs are more likely to be informative, especially on Windows XP with its primitive event logging.

Answer (score 3):

You must have permission problem. PostgreSQL on windows wants to run as a postgres user. Installer will automatically create one and assign it new password.

There are few solutions to this. If you have just installed this database, then easiest solution is to uninstall Postgres, delete local postgres user (via `control userpasswords2`) and finally install Postgres again (be sure that you have admin rights on this box). Good luck!